# Pymc3: Observed values for Dirichlet prior parameter

Tags: pymc3

I write some small pymc3 code which don't work.

```
import pymc3

def create_model_pymc(data):
    with pymc3.Model() as model:
        k = 3
        #discussion about conjugate prior of a dirichlet are not so common see http://andrewgelman.com/2009/04/29/conjugate_prior/
        #u = pymc3.Uniform("u", lower=.1, upper=data.max()+1., observed=data, shape=k)
        u = pymc3.Exponential('u', 1./10, observed=data, shape=k)
        p = pymc3.Dirichlet('p', a=u, shape=k)
        c = pymc3.Categorical('c', p=p)
    return model

alpha_posterior = np.array([10., 3., 4.])
model = create_model_pymc(alpha_posterior)

with model:
    step = pymc3.Metropolis(model.vars)
    trace = pymc3.sample(20000, step)
    #trace = pymc3.sample(20000)
```

I got an theano error "IndexError: index out of bounds" error message, but I don't know why. I tried different variations of the code above, but all of them don't work.

If you a curious about the meaning of the code, it's for
checking that the posterior of the dirichlet parameters after 
observing the multinomial counts: (10, 3, 4) for the three classes
with a "uniform" dirichlet prior (alpha=[1.,1.,1.]) results
in (10.,3.,4.)

Simple direct sampling:

```
a=alpha_posterior
print a
nb_samples = 200000
c_ = np.ndarray(nb_samples)
for i in range(nb_samples):
    d = scipy.stats.dirichlet.rvs(a,1)[0]
    c_[i] = np.random.choice(3, 1, p=d)
ns = float(nb_samples)

print (c_==0).sum()/ns
print (c_==1).sum()/ns
print (c_==2).sum()/ns
print x
print x/float(x.sum())
```

Comment: Any progress on this?

Answer (score 0):

This code worked fine for me with no errors.

```
import numpy as np
import pymc3

with pymc3.Model() as model:
    data = np.array([10., 3., 4.])
    k = 3
    u = pymc3.Exponential('u', 1./10, observed=data, shape=k)
    p = pymc3.Dirichlet('p', a=u, shape=k)
    c = pymc3.Categorical('c', p=p)
    step = pymc3.Metropolis()
    trace = pymc3.sample(20, step)
```

> Only 20 samples in chain.
>
> Multiprocess sampling (4 chains in 4 jobs)
>
> CompoundStep
>
> Metropolis: [c]
>   Metropolis: [p]
>   Sampling 4 chains: 100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 2080/2080 [00:02<00:00, 893.84draws/s]